Reader set-considering, interactive, book writing app
I am looking for a reader set-considering, interactive, book writing app.
In the app, you can define a set of faces that could be like students in your class. For each face, you can specify a few things about the person.
This would be the top part of the app.
In the bottom part, you write the text.
As you highlight text in the bottom part, you can click on any one of the faces on the top part, to view the character's reaction as computed by the AI based on the things specified about the character and the text.
The reaction can be viewed in a cloud, by the face.
This would be a very useful app for PCs and smatphones, and would be useful for writing books that gained a wide audience.
The app could also make suggestions, as you wrote.
Is there any such app out there.
Would anyone be willing to develop such an app?
Contributions, welcome.
Thanks.
